# suppressing sorting in dataTables in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have a dataTable in Shiny but I want to disable sorting and get rid of the arrows next to the column headings as exemplified in the following image.

[image]

I have used the following code to attempt to disble it with no luck.

```
output$ex <-
  renderDataTable({inData},
                  options = list(
                      bLengthChange = 0,
                      bFilter       = 0,
                      bInfo         = 0,
                      bPaginate     = 0,
                      bSortable     = 0,
                      bOrderable    = 0),
                  rownames=FALSE)
```

I thought `bSortable=0`, `bOrderable=0` would do the trick but doesn't make it work.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try

```
datatable(iris,options = list(ordering=F))
```

to remove sorting

And

```
datatable(iris,options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
```

to show only table

Comment: Works great and not so intuitive for me as all the other options in the list started with the B and ended with = 0. Thanks!

Comment: `ordering=0` also work ( simply 0\1 as bool == FALSE\TRUE)