# Table Visuals in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, sass, css-selectors

I wanted to add my own visual graphics to a table in R Shiny, but I don't have experience in SASS/CSS or know how to put SASS/CSS in a Shiny app full of R code. I do know that they can be put inside a dashboard, but not on a table inside the dashboard. If I want to specify borders, background fill, font color, make texts bold, and add a merged row, how do I go about the execution?

Below is an example of the said table(s):
[image] [image]

**I wanted to achieve something like this:**

[image]

I wanted to specify the first merged row with the background color `#806000` and font color `#FFFFFF`, second row with background color `#B61F06` and font color `#FFFFFF`, border lines on certain portions of the table, and bold text in the last row. How do I go about achieving this?

Code for the tables:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1:4), c("Z", "Y", "X", "A"),c(0.55,0.76,0.77,0.24),c(0.74,0.47,0.69,0.51))
df2 <- data.frame(c(6.99, 4.99), c("C","D"), c(0.55,0.76), c(0.74,0.47))
colnames(df1) <- c("Col1", "Col2","Col3","Col4")
colnames(df2) <- c("Col1", "Col2","Col3","Col4")

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(xtable)
library(withr)
library(shinybusy)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("th"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    add_busy_spinner(spin = "cube-grid", onstart = FALSE),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            radioButtons(
              inputId = "filter1", label = "Table", inline = TRUE,
              choiceNames = c("One", "Two"), choiceValues = c("df1", "df2")
            )
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(box(
          id = "table-container",
          column(8, align = "center", offset = 2, tags$b(textOutput("text1"))), br(), br(),
          textOutput("text2"),
          tableOutput("static1"),
          width = 12
          ))
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    "This Table"
  })
  
  output$text2 <- renderText({
    "PR TESTING TABLE"
  })
  
  df02 <- reactive({
    df<- get(input$filter1)
    df[dim(df)[1]+1,2]<- "Average"
    df[dim(df)[1],3]<- mean(df$Col3,na.rm = TRUE)
    df[dim(df)[1],4]<- mean(df$Col4,na.rm = TRUE)
    df[dim(df)[1],1]<-""
    df
  })
  
  output$static1 <- renderTable({
    df02()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Apart from what @shghm has answered, I found this post that maybe it could give you some help to add the colors to the table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929185/how-to-change-background-and-text-color-of-dt-datable-header-in-r-shiny

Comment: @emr2 I think this is solely for a dynamic DT Datatable. If I want this in a static table using renderTable, how do I embed the CSS code inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to get the exact result that you were expecting but I got something close.

I know that you wanted to have a static table using `renderTable` but I only found things for `DT`. To "hide" some of the options of DT, I have included some parameters (for example, suppressing sorting, the search option...)

Basically, the new code is the following one:

#ui

```
# I put width = 6 to avoid having the full width of the table.
DT::dataTableOutput("static1", width = 6)
```

#server

```
myContainer <- reactive({
    htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = ncol(df02()), 'PR TESTING TABLE'),
        ),
        tr(
          lapply(names(df02()), th)
        )
      )
    ))
  }) 
  
  
  
  output$static1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df02(),  rownames= FALSE, container = myContainer(),
                  class = 'cell-border stripe',
                  options = list(
                    dom='t',
                    ordering=F,
                    initComplete = JS(
                      "function(settings, json) {",
                      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#b31b1b', 'color': 'white'});",
                      "}")
                    )
    )
    
    
  })
```

Result:

[image: image1]
[image: image 2]

The links that I have used to get the result:

- [Supressing sorting in DT](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848626/suppressing-sorting-in-datatables-in-shiny)
- [Change column width.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205410/r-shiny-set-datatable-column-width)
- [Add borders to the table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918085/how-do-you-add-column-borders-for-a-shiny-datatable)
- [Change color of the header.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929185/how-to-change-background-and-text-color-of-dt-datable-header-in-r-shiny)
- [Table containers (to merge several columns in one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63735805/including-table-containers-in-dtdatatable-in-r)

Complete code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1:4), c("Z", "Y", "X", "A"),c(0.55,0.76,0.77,0.24),c(0.74,0.47,0.69,0.51))
df2 <- data.frame(c(6.99, 4.99), c("C","D"), c(0.55,0.76), c(0.74,0.47))
colnames(df1) <- c("Col1", "Col2","Col3","Col4")
colnames(df2) <- c("Col1", "Col2","Col3","Col4")

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(xtable)
library(withr)
library(shinybusy)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data Table", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("th"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    add_busy_spinner(spin = "cube-grid", onstart = FALSE),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            radioButtons(
              inputId = "filter1", label = "Table", inline = TRUE,
              choiceNames = c("One", "Two"), choiceValues = c("df1", "df2")
            )
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(box(
          id = "table-container",
          column(8, align = "center", offset = 2, tags$b(textOutput("text1"))), br(), br(),
          textOutput("text2"),
          DT::dataTableOutput("static1", width = 6),
          width = 12
        ))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    "This Table"
  })
  
  
  df02 <- reactive({
    df<- get(input$filter1)
    df[dim(df)[1]+1,2]<- "Average"
    df[dim(df)[1],3]<- mean(df$Col3,na.rm = TRUE)
    df[dim(df)[1],4]<- mean(df$Col4,na.rm = TRUE)
    df[dim(df)[1],1]<-""
    df
  })
  
  myContainer <- reactive({
    htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = ncol(df02()), 'PR TESTING TABLE'),
        ),
        tr(
          lapply(names(df02()), th)
        )
      )
    ))
  }) 
  
  
  
  output$static1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df02(),  rownames= FALSE, container = myContainer(),
                  class = 'cell-border stripe',
                  options = list(
                    dom='t',
                    ordering=F,
                    initComplete = JS(
                      "function(settings, json) {",
                      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#b31b1b', 'color': 'white'});",
                      "}")
                    )
    )
    
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: This helps a lot! I'm assuming that the ```initComplete = JS()``` portion is the JavaScript/CSS, so I'll look into whether I can further change/ specify the color of the header individually.

Comment: According to what it appears in the help of R, the function `JS()` marks character vectors with a special class, so that it will be treated as literal JavaScript code when evaluated on the client-side. It is an object that the `DT` package imported from other packages (`htmlwidgets`). I am glad that the answer helps:). May I ask you to vote for the answer, please? Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

The `gt` package might be a good starting point as it has a vast variety of options, can bind cells together and is not too complicated to learn / use (at least IMHO). It also works well with Shiny.

Link: https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html